# Pool of preloaded iframes

Tags: html, iframe, loading

My application just loads a real HTML page first time (*header*, *content*, *sidebar* and *footer*). Then each click on a link is loaded through AJAX and displayed (just loads new *content*).

Some ajax loaded *content* contents one or more iframes. Some users are reporting that when they click on some pages (click on a *sidebar* link) the page takes too much time to load. These pages they report are pages with 4 or 5 iframes inside. The application sends something like:

```
<div>
    Content...
    <iframe style="display:none" src="URL1"></iframe>
    <iframe style="display:none" src="URL2"></iframe>
    <iframe style="display:none" src="URL3"></iframe>
    <iframe style="display:none" src="URL4"></iframe>
    More content...
</div>
```

Iframes are initially hidden and displayed on user request (is not possible to load on user request because it makes even worst the user experience). So the problem is how to make these iframes load faster on page loading.

I've thought on make an iframe pool so I'll just load 5 iframes at the first page load (when I load the header, sidebar and footer) and then reuse these Iframes on demand, so the AJAX call will return a piece of code like this:

```
<div>
    Content...
    <div class="iframe" style="display:none" src="URL1"></div>
    <div class="iframe" style="display:none" src="URL2"></div>
    <div class="iframe" style="display:none" src="URL3"></div>
    <div class="iframe" style="display:none" src="URL4"></div>
    More content...
</div>
```

and the *success* callback will assign each *div.iframe* with its corresponding iframe.

Will be enough to speed up the page loading and improve user experience? Is there any jquery plugin or code that already do this or similar? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: I dunno if I understood your problem well, but do you want to create this pool of preloaded iframes for performance purposes? If it is so, then I think it will not help to increase speed, cos you will have to load the main page and create this additional pool of iframes.

Comment: @Victor: I'll preload some iframes once, when main page is loaded. After that, I never load main page again (unless user forces a page reloading), just load parts of the page using AJAX. The point is that these AJAX loaded content sometimes contains iframes. If so, I'll (re)use the iframes in the pool.

Comment: Where do these iframes point to? What is the performance of those URLs. There is some "tax" when creating iframes, but that is usually dwarfed by the loading of the iframe itself in most cases.

Comment: These iframes are pointing to my own site and the problems are most more noticiable in IE (surprise!). I haven't any reliable performance measure, but to load a *content* without frames in localhost (through AJAX) is near unappreciable (100 or 200 miliseconds?) and load a *content* with 5 frames is about 2 seconds.

Comment: what are these iframes for? why load so many of them?

Answer (score 1):

Ivan,

You could load your first page fully, and then begin to load the iframes using AJAX into some sort of cache (JSON strings perhaps?). As you say - you can then load the cached content as the user requests it. Remember to also cater for people that have javascript disabled.

If you find that the request to load iframes as they are needed (not pre-loaded) it's worth investigating why they are slow to load. What happens when you load the iframe src directly?

Why do you use so many iframes? If they are all pointing to external websites, this will slow down load times quite a bit as each page will have to render before your AJAX request can pull the content into your page. If they are pointing to internal (local) pages, then perhaps look at not using them?

Comment: I do so :) I load my first page (the *content*)  and then I load the iframes, but leaving this task to the browser. I believe it won't be faster to load it using AJAX, have you had any experience in that? The problem is that the main page is not loaded until all frames are loaded (iframes are a kind of pluings).
Iframes are strictly needed (see Christoph comment) and internal. No need to worry about javascript disabled browsers.

Comment: Ivan, the main thing is how you load the iframe content. This should be triggered once everything else on your page is loaded so that AJAX will pull the iframe content into a cache after the user sees a fully rendered first page. You can use AJAX to load the iframe content directly, and then write this into an iframe(s) element that you create with javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: As long as you have control over all the content and you have no serious arguments to do so, you should not use iframes. They add quite some overhead, are not good for SEO, and are unhandy to work with.

Also try to make the initial pageload as lightweight as possible. Don't preload everything, but use asynchronous calls to fetch the rest of the content (beginning with the stuff which is most likely to be requested next by the user).

Don't be afraid to let the user wait some time. He is used to the fact, that when a link is clicked, that there is some waiting time. Important is, that you indicate, that something is happening (use a [spinner](http://ajaxload.info/) for that).

Another important aspect when using AJAX is the history. The user expects the back- (and forward-)button to work as intended. AJAX doesn't support that per se. Consider using a jquery history pugin like [this one](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) to significantly improve the user-friendliness of your application.

I would do someting like this:

```
<div id="content1" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="content2" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="content3" style="display:none"></div>

loadContent();

function loadContent(){
   // asynchronously load content1, upon success content2, and so on,
   // until all resources are loaded
}
```

now your ajax call only contains the data for each single div without any overhead. This saves bandwidth and speeds up the loading-time - by breaking up the content in pieces, the client can respond faster (If you don't have problems with more http-request arising via this method).

Comment: SEO is not important (spiders haven't access to these pages, are an internal application). IFrames are mandatory, due some pages (*contents*) share the same IDs.